# ionic popover not opened over where mouse clicked place

Tags: css, angularjs

I am new to ionic & angular. How to open popover over clicked place?. I can achieve this at in header position, but in bottom of the page cant reach this requirement. If I placed a button at bottom of the page, that button click to open a popover. It will open at center of the page only. But it should open over the button. Please help me to reach my requirement.
I had mentioned my worked out code. Thanks in advance for your valuable response.

```
<button class="button button-clear button-dark " ng-readonly="details.checkstatus==false"  style="margin-right:15px;width:100%" ng-click="viewTaskColor($event)">
                                            <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-filled icon-align-right " style="color:{{details.color}};float:right"></i>
                                        </button>

 $scope.viewTaskColor = function ($event) {
        $scope.TaskColor.show($event);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share code snippet that you tried?

Comment: `style = "z-index: 999"`

Comment: If you don't provide the click "event" then it will float. 
`<button ion-button (click)="showOptions($event)">
                <ion-icon name="cog"></ion-icon>
            </button>`
then create the popover and pass the $event item on the present call:
`popover.present({ev:$event});`

Comment: @mhughes2k this is the correct answer, please move it to answer section.